# Ping to check for connectivity to a domain

Tags: java, android, networking, ping

In my android application I am querying a database. I am only able to query the database if the phone is connected to the internal network, i.e: by being connected to company WiFi, or by using VPN connection.

I would like to check this connection first - maybe by trying to 'ping' the server first? Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: you should connect to network before pinging it. that is how networking works.

Comment: I'm developing this for the end user, so I'm expecting the fact that they will not always connect to the network first. They will launch the application, and once it force closes/hangs due to inability to find the DNS, they're going to get confused. I understand that's how networking works, but my end users do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to connect to the network/database/ip and handle any exception thrown b/c the network is unreachable or b/c of a time out.

You can also try [InetAddress](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) which has an isReachable() method.

Comment: To the internal IP address of the database you are trying to reach.

Comment: Write the code as if you are assuming you are on the right network and handle the exception if the connection does not go through. The exception can notify the user that the network is unreachable (aka the user is not on the right network)

Comment: I would like the user to fix the problem before attempting to do any of the queries. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using android.net.ConectivityManager if you really want to check the network status.

ConectivityManager.requestRouteToHost() can be used to ensure a server is reachable (although doubts have been raised about its reliability - mentioned in CommonsWare answer here : [how to mange wifi internet connectivity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635374/how-to-mange-wifi-internet-connectivity-in-android) )

Alternatively, if you just want to check WIFI is connected, try

ConectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()

Couple of caveats :

1) I'm typing this in a browser not an IDE, so it might have syntax errors,

2) You'll have to make that code much more defensive for production, and

3) All connectivity tests in ConectivityManager can be unreliable if networks are currently becoming available or unavailable.

Hope this covers what you were asking.